# I want to create multiple objects in list<object> and remove them with the desired id

Tags: c#, list, listobject

I want to delete it with the desired id.

Can you tell me if there is another way to do it with Linq?

I think I can use Select() and Where(), but it doesn't work.

```
var list = new List<object>() { };
list.Add(new { id = 3, const = "22"});
list.Add(new { id = 4, const = "22"});
list.Add(new { id = 6, const = "22"});
list.Add(new { id = 2, const = "22"});
list.Add(new { id = 1, const = "22"});

//example
list.Remove(new { id = 2, const = "22" });
```

Comment: could you please be more specific than `doesn't work`? and maybe even include the code that "doesn't work"? welcome to stackoverflow. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I wrote the code I want to do in a sample format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all `const` is a keyword in C#, so either avoid using it as member name, or escape it by decorating with `@`.

since your list item type is `object`, you need to cast them as `dynamic` to allow access the 'unknown' `id` -> this a very vague approach, but it works.
`=` in C# means: set the value of... so if you want to compare equality, you need `==`

putting this altogether:

```
  var list = new List<object>();
  list.Add(new { id = 4, @const = "22" });
  list.Add(new { id = 4, @const = "22" });
  list.Add(new { id = 6, @const = "22" });
  list.Add(new { id = 2, @const = "22" });
  list.Add(new { id = 1, @const = "22" });

  list.RemoveAll(i => ((dynamic)i).id == 2);
```

will work.

Consider using an own Type for your list items, anonymous types should only be used 'locally' in Queries like `GroupBy`.

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
list.RemoveAt(list.FindIndex(item => item.id == 1));
```